# How to put buttons next to Navigation Bar Title?

Tags: swift, xcode

How do you put the buttons next to the NavigationBarTitle in SwiftUI, exactly like iOS 13 messages app. I've tried navigationBarItems and it's not the same result. That function places the elements above the title. Is there away way to place buttons exactly like the screenshot I've provided?

[Example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyaeZ.jpg)